# Error in starting gradle project while using Spring Boot to Consume from Kafka: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on ..."

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, build.gradle, spring-kafka

I am trying to build a simple consumer using spring boot to consume data from a kafka topic. However I get the following error before startup of the spring boot application:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.2.RELEASE)

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.client.RestTemplateAutoConfiguration.restTemplateBuilder
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:337)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.gs.eq.art.rec.Start.main(Start.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:743)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:742)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:681)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:649)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1604)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:491)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:230)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:223)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:213)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:167)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/ReactiveTransactionManager
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.transaction.ReactiveTransactionManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 37 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

My project is a sub project of an existing gradle project. The build.gradle file for my sub project is as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:${SpringKafkaVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:${SpringBootVersion}"
}
```

Java classes:

Start.java:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Start {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Application Started");
            SpringApplication.run(Start.class, args);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

KafkaConsumerConfig.java:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.UUID;

@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        HashMap<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(
                ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                <KAFKA_SERVER_ADDRESS>);
        props.put(
                ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,
                UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        props.put(
                ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(
                ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>
    kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
```

KafkaConsumer.java

```
@Service
public class KafkaConsumer {

    @KafkaListener(topics = <TOPIC_NAME>)
    public void consume(@Payload ConsumerRecord<String, String> message) {
        System.out.println("Consumed message: " + message);
    }
}
```

The KAFKA_SERVER_ADDRESS and TOPIC_NAME have been correctly provided within my code.

Any ideas as to what the issue could potentially be?

Comment: try replacing `spring-boot-starter` with `spring-boot-starter-web`

Comment: thanks for that. it fixed the issue. Btw now that the application is running, no messages are being consumed in the kafka listener. I have made sure that AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG is set to earliest and that I have a uniques group id. Any idea why i don't receive messages from the topic?

Comment: correction: realised I was unclear. replacing spring-boot-starter to spring-boot-starter-web didn't solve the issue, it caused another exception (Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration'). However the issue has been fixed with javichuuu's answer below. If you could help with why I still may not be able to consume from a kafka topic then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include **'spring transaction'** dependency (**org.springframework:spring-tx**) in your build.gradle.

I suggest you use **dependencyManagement** to be sure you use the correct dependencies and compatible versions.

Comment: Hi. I included this dependency and thr application started. Thanks alot for that. Why is it important to include this dependency in build.gradle? Also when I start the application, nothing actually gets consumed from the kafka topic. Do you know why that might be the case?

Comment: That dependency its a requeriment to spring kafka ( see it on https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.kafka/spring-kafka/2.4.0.RELEASE for example). Idk how you add dependency to your classpath.Should have added automatically. Add dependencyManagement to be sure you have compatible versions.

Comment: Thanks. I added the dependency and was able to start the application. Could you please check my question as to being unable to consume messages from kafka topic:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59616956/spring-boot-kafka-consumer-using-gradle-not-consuming-kafka-listener-not-trigge

Comment: answered in the other post